# Subprocess Hexdump Command Returning Bad Format Error

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, hexdump

I am utilizing subprocess in order to grab the hexdump for a .tgz file as I require the hex string. The only problem is, hexdump is throwing a bad format error, but only when the command is issues through subprocess. I believe I have escaped everything correctly, but I can't figure out why I am not getting my intended output:

```
def package_plugin():
    plugin_hex = subprocess.run(["hexdump", "-v", "-e", "'1/1 \"\\\\x%%02x\"'", "package.tgz"])
```

This results in an error: **hexdump: "'1/1 "''x%%02x"'": bad format**. However, if I just run the command straight in the terminal I receive the expected output of a hexstring with the '\x' separating the hex.

How should I be running this to store the output in a Python variable? Is my command being mangled somehow and hence not executing correctly? Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: I should add that when entering in the terminal the command is `hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\x%02x"'` I am not sure why the extra '%' sign is shown in the error as it should be interpreting as a single % sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I couldn't figure this out but I solved it with hexlify:

```
def package_plugin():
    plugin_hex = ""
    with open('plugin.tgz', 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(32), b''):
            plugin_hex += binascii.hexlify(chunk).decode("utf-8")

    formatted_hex = '\\x' + '\\x'.join(plugin_hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(plugin_hex), 2))
```